# How to know when an AVSpeechUtterance has finished, so as to continue app activity?

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

When an `AVSpeechUtterance` is speaking, I want to wait until it's finished before doing something else.

There is a property of `AVSpeechSynthesizer` that's seemingly indicative of when speech is occuring:

[`isSpeaking`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizer/1619680-isspeaking)

As stupid and simple as this question might sound, I'm wondering how do I use/check this property to wait until speech has concluded before going on?

**ALTERNATIVELY:**

There's a delegate, that I'm also clueless as to how to use, which has an ability to do something when an utterance has finished:

[`AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avspeechsynthesizerdelegate)

There's an answer, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335310/objective-c-wait-for-avspeechsynthesizer-until-it-finishes-speaking-a-word), that says to use this. But that doesn't help me because I don't know how to use a Delegate.

### UPDATE:

This is how I setup my speaking class:

```
import AVFoundation

class CanSpeak: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

    let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
    let voiceSynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var voiceToUse: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?

    override init(){
        voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter({ $0.name == "Karen" }).first
    }

    func sayThis(_ phrase: String){
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: phrase)
        utterance.voice = voiceToUse
        utterance.rate = 0.5
        voiceSynth.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

### UPDATE 2: Wrongheaded workaround...

using the above mentioned `isSpeaking` property, in the gameScene:

```
voice.sayThis(targetsToSay)

    let initialPause = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 1.0)
    let holdWhileSpeaking = SKAction.run {
        while self.voice.voiceSynth.isSpeaking {print("STILL SPEAKING!")}
    }
    let pauseAfterSpeaking = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.5)
    let doneSpeaking = SKAction.run {print("TIME TO GET ON WITH IT!!!")}

run(SKAction.sequence(
    [   initialPause,
        holdWhileSpeaking,
        pauseAfterSpeaking,
        doneSpeaking
    ]))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delegate pattern is one of the most common used design pattern in object-oriented programming, it's not as hard as it seems. For your case, you can simply let your class (a game scene) to be a delegate of the CanSpeak class.

```
protocol CanSpeakDelegate {
   func speechDidFinish()
}
```

Next set AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate to your CanSpeak class, declare CanSpeakDelegate and then use AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate delegate function.

```
class CanSpeak: NSObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {

   let voices = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices()
   let voiceSynth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
   var voiceToUse: AVSpeechSynthesisVoice?

   var delegate: CanSpeakDelegate!

   override init(){
      voiceToUse = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice.speechVoices().filter({ $0.name == "Karen" }).first
      self.voiceSynth.delegate = self
   }

   func sayThis(_ phrase: String){
      let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: phrase)
      utterance.voice = voiceToUse
      utterance.rate = 0.5
      voiceSynth.speak(utterance)
   }

   func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
      self.delegate.speechDidFinish()
   }
}
```

Lastly in your game scene class, simply conform to CanSpeakDelegate and set it as the delegate of your CanSpeak class.

```
class GameScene: NSObject, CanSpeakDelegate {

   let canSpeak = CanSpeak()

   override init() {
      self.canSpeak.delegate = self
   }

   // This function will be called every time a speech finishes
   func speechDidFinish() {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, super stupid question: Why does the definition/declaration of `func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
      self.delegate.speechDidFinish()
   }` contain placeholders and never seemingly have them called?

Comment: They can be used for other purposes, for example you have more than 1 AVSpeechSynthesizer in your CanSpeak class. How do you tell which one is has finishes its speech? There's where the variables declared in the function comes it. if synthesizer == mySynthesizerA { // do something }

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. How is this function ever called, without parameters? It seems to require an AVSpeechSynthesizer and an utterance, but I don't see when/where/how those are passed to this function.

Comment: And (another) stupid question, when you declare `var delegate: CanSpeakDelegate!` does this mean that any class can have a delegate of its abilities created?

Comment: The function is called from the AVSpeechSynthesizer class itself, which is written by Apple. Within AVSpeechSynthesizer there is a var delegate: AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate! variable declared, which is why you can set self.voiceSynth.delegate = self. 

Yes, all classes can have delegates of its abilities created. In swift delegates are mostly created as a protocol so that a class can conforms to it.

Comment: Perhaps I'm asking a SUPER STUPID question: how does the calling of this function get done with the required parameters? Does the framework somehow guess what to fill in, from surrounding context?

Comment: Inside the AVSpeechSynthesizer class, when the speech ends, it will call the delegate function self.delegate.speechSynthesizer(synthesizer: self, didFinish utterance: self.utterance), that's when the AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate function in your CanSpeak class will be called.

Comment: So there's no way for me to say (bad pun) have three different utterances, each resulting in unique calls to didFinish?

Comment: The problem with this approach, that I see, is that every time I have the voice instance of CanSpeak say something, the didFinish function is called, and everything in it invoked. I don't want that to be the case. There are different things being said at different times, some of which need to be followed by different activity than the others. Hence the careful phrasing of the initial question to an AVSpeechUtterance. These utterances are unique, as are the subsequent activities.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129309/discussion-between-koropok-and-confused).

Comment: I might be wrong about this, but this line might be wrong `self.canSpeak.delegate = self`, maybe it shouldn't be self?

Comment: it is correct. you need to set your synthesizer class's delegate to your game scene class.

Comment: Can either of you suggest how to use this solution if GameScene were a UIViewController instead of NSObject type? When trying to implement this very well thought out solution, I run into errors when trying to do the ```override init()``` portion in GameScene getting the error that ```Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass```. I'm assuming because it is UIViewController and not NSObject.

Comment: @CaseSilva simply remove the `override` and call a designated initializer of `UIViewController` within it.

Answer (score 3):

Sets up delegate to your AVSpeechSynthesizer instance.

`voiceSynth.delegate = self`

Then, implements `didFinish` method as below:

```
func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, 
                  didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
    // Implements here.
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm trying to make the search for the end of speech in another class, not the CanSpeak class. So that probably needs to be the delegate? I'm not sure how this works. In the class (a game scene) it calls an instance of CanSpeak.sayThis("Text to Say"). After that, I'm completely lost as to how to use this delegate and its function. Even what to put in the parameters of the function call you show... dunno.

Comment: Even trickier, for me, how would I return to flow of the program from calling this didFinish method in the CanSpeak instance? Sorry. STUPID questions. no idea how to do this delegate handling/creation/control

Comment: This "answer" doesn't provide any more information than the apple docs. If I could figure out how to use this from the Apple docs, I wouldn't be asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate` with method:

```
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(AVSpeechSynthesizer *)synthesizer didFinishSpeechUtterance:(AVSpeechUtterance *)utterance;
```

Comment: I've updated question, I see that this exists. I don't know how to use it in Swift, let alone Objective-C.

Comment: So maybe this tutorial can help you: http://www.appcoda.com/text-to-speech-ios-tutorial/

Comment: No. I can't figure out what/when/how they're using the delegate from that tutorial. It doesn't seem the function didFinish is ever called directly. I can't follow what they're doing in that tutorial.

Comment: The delegate is called automatically when trigger. In that case, func `speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, 
                  didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance)` is called directly when the speech is finished.

Comment: And your code now lack of `voiceSynth.delegate = yourImplementClass`