# Pass data back from table in modal view

Tags: swift, segue, modalviewcontroller

I think i have a problem with segue dan modal view

first, In my "ViewController 1" i have a button and variable
second, In my "ViewController 2" i have a table

all i want is when i click the table, the data is passback to the variable in "ViewController 1"

here is my didselectRowAt from my "ViewController2"

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{

    let view = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "maps") as! MAPS
    let results = data[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary
    let datageo = results["geometry"] as! NSDictionary
    let location = datageo["location"] as! NSDictionary
    let latitude = location["lat"] as! Double
    let longtitude = location["lng"] as! Double
    print (latitude)
    print (longtitude)
    view.dari = (results["vicinity"] as? String)!
    view.positionlatitude = latitude
    view.positionlongitude = longtitude
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any advice? , thank you ..

Comment: You can use the Delegate Pattern.

Comment: i don't understand how to use protocol. is there no other way? @koropok

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter to post a notification. It will work but it's not the optimal way.

Comment: I learning protocol right now , hope i can solve it, thanks for the advice @koropok

Comment: You can refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/40856661/6642629. It might help a little.